# How to create a list within list in python

Tags: python, json

I need a simple task to create a list within list in Python Here is the code I have tried

```
data_list = []

data = {'AgreementIdList': 'ABC123', 'Required': 'true'}

data_list.append(data)

print (data_list)
```

Actual Result:

```
[{'AgreementIdList': 'ABC123', 'Required': 'true'}]
```

Expected Result:

```
{"AgreementIdList": ["ABC123"], "Required": true}
```

Comment: Your expected result doesn't make sense. Why is the first value now in a sublist where the second isn't? And also changed from the string `'true'` to the (incorrect capitalization) bool literal `False`?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the following:

```
data['AgreementIdList'] = [data['AgreementIdList']]
val = data['Required']
if val == 'true':
    val = True    
data['Required'] = val
```

Assuming you want the following output:

```
{"AgreementIdList": ["ABC123"], "Required": True}
```

Now if you want to convert it to `json` you need to use an additional library. The following will work:

```
import json
data_list = []
data_list.append(data)
json_data = json.dumps(data_list)
print(json_data)
```

JSON Output:

```
'[{"AgreementIdList": ["ABC123"], "Required": true}]'
```

The json output can be now used to test you API.

Comment: actually I need to pass a JSON string for testing the API and payload is having true in lower case

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't necessarily want to mutate the original `data`.

```py
data = {'AgreementIdList': 'ABC123', 'Required': 'true'}
data2 = dict(data, AgreementIdList=[data['AgreementIdList']])
print(data2)
```

outputs

```
{'AgreementIdList': ['ABC123'], 'Required': 'true'}
```

On more recent Python versions, you can also use this syntax for the same effect:

```py
data = {'AgreementIdList': 'ABC123', 'Required': 'true'}
data2 = {**data, 'AgreementIdList': [data['AgreementIdList']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your data is set as a dictonary. You can find this out by running print(type(data)). So what you are actually trying to do is to add a list with one item to a dictionary. Try this:

```
data = {'AgreementIdList': 'ABC123', 'Required': 'true'}

data['AgreementIdList'] = ['ABC123']

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

For expected result:

```
data2 = {'AgreementIdList': [data['AgreementIdList']], 'Required':(data['Required']=='true')}
data2
Out[10]: {'AgreementIdList': ['ABC123'], 'Required': True}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make below change to get expected result,

```
data = {'AgreementIdList': ['ABC123'], 'Required': 'true'}
```